# Collect results into a text file

Tags: python

I need to collect and save data from BMI calculations with the app I've made, but i have no idea how to do that. I've found some kind of code that does what i need but it only

```
from Tkinter import *

raiz = Tk()
frame = Frame(raiz)
out = []

def cadastro():
    form = Toplevel(raiz)

    Label(form, text='Name: ').grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=E)
    Label(form, text='Phone number: ').grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=E)

    nome = StringVar()
    celular = StringVar()

    a=Entry(form, textvariable=nome, width=15)
    a.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=W)
    Entry(form, textvariable=celular, width=15).grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=W)

    def onCancel():
        form.destroy()

    def onOk():
        with open('outt.txt','w') as txt:
            txt.write('Name : ' + str(nome.get()) + '  ' + 'Telephone No. : ' + str(celular.get()))
        onCancel()

    Button(form, text='OK', command=onOk).grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=E)
    Button(form, text='Cancel', command=onCancel).grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=W)

def listar():
    with open('outt.txt','r') as txt_read:
        print txt_read.read()




w = Button(raiz, text='Cadastrar',command=cadastro).grid()
x = Button(raiz, text='Listar' , command=listar).grid()


raiz.mainloop()
```

That's to collect the data which doesn't work properly

and that's the calculator code

```
from tkinter import*



class mFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, labeltext=''):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.label=Label(master, text=labeltext, width=30, bg="#fb5250", fg="#fee56c", font='Arial 12')
        self.label.grid()
        self.text=StringVar()
        self.entry=Entry(master, bd=5, textvariable=self.text)
        self.entry.grid()
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.B2=Button (text='Metric', width=15,bg="#32a2ad", activebackground="#00525a")
        self.B2['command']=self.poop
        self.B2.grid()
        self.L1=mFrame(master,"Name:")
        self.L2=mFrame(master, "Height(Metres/Inches):")
        self.L3=mFrame(master, "Weight(Kilos/Pounds):")
        self.B1=Button( text='Calculate', width=20, bg="#32a2ad", activebackground="#00525a")
        self.B1['command']=self.action
        self.B1.grid()
    def poop(self):
        if self.B2['text'] == "Metric":
            self.B2['text'] = "Imperial"
        else:
            self.B2['text'] = "Metric"
    def action(self):
        c= Toplevel(root)
        c.title("BMI-Result")
        c.geometry('270x160+230+130')
        name=self.L1.text.get()
        if not self.L1.text.get():
            Label(c, text='Unacceptable name!',font='Arial 10').pack(side=TOP)
        else:
            pass
        height=self.L2.text.get()
        if not self.L2.text.get():
            Label(c, text='Write the information in this format "x.xx"',font='Arial 10').pack(side=TOP)
        elif not height.isdigit():
            try:
                height=float(self.L2.text.get())
            except ValueError:
                Label(c, text='Enter height as a number!',font='Arial 10').pack(side=TOP)
        else:
            height=float(self.L2.text.get())
            pass
        weight=self.L3.text.get()
        if not self.L3.text.get():
            Label(c, text='Write the information in this format "x.xx"',font='Arial 10').pack(side=TOP)
        elif not weight.isdigit():
            Label(c, text='Enter weight as a number!',font='Arial 10').pack(side=TOP)
        else:
            weight=float(self.L3.text.get())
            pass
            if self.B2['text'] == "Metric":
                bmi=round(float(weight)/(float(height)**2),2)
                Label(c, text=['Hello', name,],font='Arial 10').pack(side=TOP)
                Label(c, text='Your Body-Mass-Index:').pack(side=TOP)
                Label(c, text=(bmi),font='Arial 10').pack(side=TOP)
            else:
                bmi=round(float(weight/2.20462)/(float(height/39.3701)**2),2)
                Label(c, text=['Hello', name,],font='Arial 10').pack(side=TOP)
                Label(c, text='Your Body-Mass-Index:').pack(side=TOP)
                Label(c, text=(bmi),font='Arial 10').pack(side=TOP)
        if bmi>=25:
            words=('You are over weight')
            color="#fb5250"
        if bmi>=30:
            words=('You are obese')
            color="#dc3c3a"
        if bmi<=18.5:
            words=('You are underweight')
            color="#b9a797"
        if bmi >=18.5 and bmi <= 25:
            words=('Your BMI is good')
            color="#2ca947"
        Label(c, text=(words), bg=color, font='Arial 10').pack(side=TOP)
root=Tk()
root.title("BMI")
root.configure(background="#fb5250")
app=Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Which works good, i just need to collect the data.

Thanks for the advices

Comment: Write the data to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use pickle. https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html.
All you need to do is

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(obj, file)
```

And

```
pickle.load(file)
```

The one is the data stored as variables and the file is well, your file.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more? I'm very new to Python, i need to record the person's BMI and their name into a text file, don't have to write any code, just some hints on how to make it work

Comment: Collect all your data in terms of a variable. If you have a long list of data items then you should use a list or dictionary. When you have the variable collected, you can then dump to your pickle file and retrieve later. The pickle file is automatically saved to your folder/directory.